# how can I make an emission shader shine through a transparent material?

Tags: cycles-render-engine, light, shaders

I am trying to use the emission shader to make a light, but I realized that it seems to be only shining through to a limited extent:

[image: lighthouse with failed shader]

These are the nodes for the light:

[image: light nodes]

These are the nodes for the glass:

[image: glass nodes]

How can I make it so that it illuminates objects on the other side of the glass?

Comment: Do you have *No Caustics* enabled in *Render settings > Light Paths*?

Comment: oh that's what it was. thanks for pointing that out!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Make sure you have *[caustics](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Caustic_%28optics%29)* enabled by unchecking *No Caustics* in *Render settings > Light Paths*:

[image]

With caustics:

[image]

Without caustics:

[image]

Comment: All it shows for me is Reflective Caustics twice, Whats up with that (Cycles Render)?

Comment: Reflective And Refractive Sorry

Comment: @Sean The "no caustics" setting was split into separate settings for reflection and refraction a while back. In this case at least the refractive part should be enabled to allow rays through the glass material.